# How to add google maps in particular part in the screen in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-fragments

Simply , I want to do something like the left photo (screen contain map and simple buttons).

[image: images here.]

I use fragment in the white space in the right photo to add map in it but the map not appear when i run the App (still white space as photo).

Any help?

Comment: check your map api key.

Comment: yeah. check your api key.  For Marshmallow and above you need to check for permissions at runtime. post your code here so we can help you better